# Jpa entity as sorted

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Employee entity class and I want a sorted list whenever I call 'List'. how can I do this in Spring boot?

I have implements Comparable with my entity class but I think that is not the write way.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Do you want to sort in your code or in your query?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort un your code try this: (here you list will be sorted by name for example)

```
List<Employee> employees = employeeRepository.findAll();
Collections.sort(employees, new Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
        return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
    }
});
```

If you are using a `Spring Data repository` to access your data, you can use the Sort class to specify the sort order when you call the `findAll()` like this:

```
List<Employee> employees = employeeRepository.findAll(Sort.by("name"));
```

Or if you want to sort it in your query, try this: (here you list will be sorted by name for example)

```
List<Employee> employees = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e ORDER BY e.name", Employee.class).getResultList();
```

But, in general, it is a good practice to perform sorting and filtering operations in the database rather than in the application code

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i want whenever i use List<Employee> it would give me the sorted one based on any field.

Comment: Okay, how/where do you want to specify the fied of sorting ?

Comment: I want in my Employee entity class. My requirement is when I use List<Employee> this list always give me the sorted list.